# Pass variable from one controller to another laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to pass the request variable from a form request to another controller (the second controller is going to have a lot of code in it so I want to use it to keep the main controller clean), but when I try and pass the variable over, nothing happens, the variable data isn't sent over.

Here is my current code:

```
class mainController extends Controller{

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validation


        $otherClass = (new secondController)->createDBEntry($request);
    }

}

class secondController extends Controller{

public function createDBEntry($request)
    {
        return $request;
    }

}
```

However, nothing is passed from the $request into the secondController. If I echo something in the secondController it works no problem, so I know it's being called, but the data isn't being sent over. What am I missing here? Keep in mind I am fairly new to laravel and I am using 5.4.

Comment: What do you mean by "the data isn't being sent over"? Are you getting an error? `null` ?

Comment: @louisfischer There are no errors or anything, just a blank page.

Comment: Well you are not returning anything. But your code should work just fine. Try adding `dd($otherClass);` after the line `$otherClass = (new secondController...`.

Comment: @louisfischer On my main controller, if I return the request, it returns just fine, but when I try and return the request on the second controller, nothing happens.

Comment: I think I figured it out. You can see my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine. You are just expecting a behavior that is never going to happen though because:

1. `new secondController` instantiates `secondController`
2. `createDBEntry($request)` calls the method `createDBEntry` passed
   with `$request`
3. The returned value is stored in the variable `$otherClass`

And that's it! nothing more is (and will be) happening. If you want to see the value of `$otherClass` (and see your code working) you have to return it:

```
class mainController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $otherClass = new secondController
        $otherClass->createDBEntry($request);

        return $otherClass;
    }    
}

class secondController extends Controller
{
    public function createDBEntry($arg)
    {
        return $arg;
    }
}
```